# Android error while compressing image from gallery

Tags: android, image, compression

I am trying to compress the images I selected from the  gallery in the onActivityResult() method.But I get a `NullPointerException`

Code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
            ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);

            for(int i=0;i<images.size();i++){
                uri=Uri.parse(images.get(i).path);
                if(i==0){
                    try {
                        imageStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);


                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 150, stream);

                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    try {

                        stream.close();


                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
```

Error:

```
03-04 18:04:36.788 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee E/uri: /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20170303_144522.jpg
03-04 18:04:36.788 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20170303_144522.jpg
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1070)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:925)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:650)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee.AddOffers.AddOffers.onActivityResult(AddOffers.java:145)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6441)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4001)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4048)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1479)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
03-04 18:04:36.798 8077-8077/com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4005)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4048)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1479)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.example.jobinsabu.ohxee.AddOffers.AddOffers.onActivityResult(AddOffers.java:140)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6441)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4001)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4048) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1479) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: You appear to be using a third-party library here, as `INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES` does not appear in the Android SDK. Which library are you using?

Comment: Oh..sorry I forgot to mention I am using https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect

Comment: Hmmm... well, `bmp` is `null`. If you log the `uri` values, what do they look like?

Comment: /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/20170303_144522.jpg This is how it is shown

Comment: The imagepath is shown when I logged it. But at the same time FileNotFoundException is also shown.Please have a look at the edited question

Comment: I do not know how that library is getting that filesystem path. That is an image from removable storage, and you are not supposed to have access to arbitrary files on removable storage.